# Kyrie Eleison is Greek, but what is the proper Latin Translation?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, ecclesiastical-latin, christianity, greek-to-latin-translation

As far as I know, these are the only Greek words in the Catholic Mass. What is their translation to Latin?

I'm aware of [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kyrie), which discusses the history and the Greek. At the very bottom is a seemingly inaccurate translation into Latin as: **Domine, miserere nobis**. “Kyrie Eleison” is Greek for “Lord have mercy” not “Lord have mercy *on us*.” I’m looking specifically for a Latin translation of *Kyrie Eleison*.

Answer (score 6):

It's not very common to see this sentence in full, translated in liturgy. The closest, most common, full translation I can think of would be:

> [**Miserere nostri, Domine**](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=miserere%20nostri%20domine)

E.g. in the [Te Deum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Te_Deum#Text).

It is much more common to see the 'have mercy on us' (eleison) part translated as *miserere nobis* (e.g. in the [Gloria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gloria_in_excelsis_Deo#Present-day_Latin_text)), hence **Domine, miserere nobis** or **miserere nobis Domine** would also sound familiar and are pretty good translations.

In both,

- **miserere** means *have mercy*. This verb can be followed by either [dative or genitive](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmisereo). It exists both as a deponent and non-deponent verb (in pre-classical Latin), though the former is more common in ecclesiastical Latin.
- **nobis** and **nostri** both mean [*on*] *us*, depending on a choice between dative or genitive for miserere
- **Domine** is the vocative of *Dominus*, *Lord*, as directly addressing Him.

---

A more literal translation like **miserere, Domine** is harder to find in liturgy, and I think it is because in Latin it is more idiomatic to have mercy on [something/someone] than to just have mercy. (I can't think of any instance of the complement being omitted.)